# How to use EventBus for non-Presenter class in GWTP?

Tags: gwt, gwtp, event-bus

I am using GWTP platform & eClipse to build webapp. In Eclipse, when creating a Presenter, it will create 3 files (ex: SearchPresenter.java, SearchView.java, & SearchView.ui.xml):

```
public class SearchView extends ViewImpl implements SearchPresenter.MyView

public class SearchPresenter extends
    Presenter<SearchPresenter.MyView, SearchPresenter.MyProxy>{
    ....
    private EventBus eventBus;
    @Inject
    public SearchPresenter(final EventBus eventBus, final MyView view) {
         super(eventBus, view);
        this.eventBus=eventBus;
    }
}
```

To use eventBus, we just simply use eclipse  to create EventBus file, ex MyEvent.java, then we call eventBus in SearchPresenter by using this code:

```
MyEvent mEvent=new MyEvent();
SearchPresenter.this.eventBus.fireEvent(mEvent);
```

now suppose I got a non-presenter class `public class SearchDialogBox extends DialogBox`, then my question is how can i use MyEvent in SearchDialogBox? How to getEventBus() in SearchDialogBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I' dont use GWTP, but I guess the following is ok.

```
@Inject private EventBus eventBus
```

should work (if you don't use it in SearchDialogBox constructor right away).

Otherwise try to find out which class in GWTP extends com.google.gwt.inject.client.Ginjector. Assuming it is called "MyInjector" just write :

```
private EventBus eventBus = MyInjector.INSTANCE.getEventBus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/wiki/Events.

You basically implement `HasHandlers` interface inject yourself the `EventBus`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make your SearchDialogBox to extend BaseEventHandler:

   ```
   SearchDialogBox extends BaseEventHandler<YOUR_EVENT_BUS>
   ```
2. For DialogBox use composition instead of inheritance since now your SearchDialogBox extends BaseEventHandler
3. Annotate your SearchDialogBox with @EventHandler (and @Singleton if needed)
4. In your YOUR_EVENT_BUS create at least one method that should be processed in SearchDialogBox

   - for example in YOUR_EVENT_BUS:

     `@Event(handlers = {SearchDialogBox.class}) void helloWorld();`

     and in SearchDialogBox

     ```
     `public void onHelloWorld(){...}`
     ```